# Can the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus be used here?

Tags: calculus

I would like to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on the following

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\int_{-\infty}^{g(x)}f(t-g(x))h(t)\operatorname{d}\!t.$$

I know how I would do this if $f(t-g(x))$ were replaced with $f(t)$, but can anything be done if the integrand is a function of $x$ too?

Comment: You can't use the FTC alone here -- I think you ought to end up with something that involves a convolution of $f'$ and $h$. In any case, start setting $y=g(x)$ and then separating $g$ from the integral using the chain rule ...

Comment: Long story short: because $x$ appears in the integrand, there is no reason to believe that the derivative can be expressed without using an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can... sort of.  A neat way to approach this is to apply a multivariate chain rule: define
$$
F(y_1,y_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{g(y_1)} f(t - g(y_2))h(t)\,dt
$$
we then have
$$
\frac {d}{dx} F(x,x) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_1}(x,x) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_2}(x,x)
$$
Notably, we can use the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to find
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2} \int_{-\infty}^{g(y_1)} f(t - g(y_2))h(t)\,dt = 
 \int_{-\infty}^{g(y_1)} \frac{\partial}{\partial y_2}f(t - g(y_2))h(t)\,dt = \\
 \int_{-\infty}^{g(y_1)} -g'(y_2)f'(t - g(y_2))h(t)\,dt
$$

Comment: I am surprised it works out this way in the sense that I expected the terms to be multiplied by each other, not summed. It was interesting trying this same method on $\int_{0}^{x^{2}} t dt$ by writing $F(y_{1},y_{2}) = \int_{0}^{y_{1}y_{2}} t dt$. Thank you

Comment: Interesting thought, I'll have to try that myself.  You're welcome