# Fundamental theorem of calculus when the integrand also contains $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm struggling with taking the derivative of the function of type $F(x) = \int _0 ^x f(x,t) dt $ with $f(x,t)$ is good: smooth, compactly supported whatsoever. $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb  R$ and $f: \mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R$.

How can I compute $\frac{d }{dx } F(x)$? Any rules or theorems? Any help and references are appreciated.

Comment: I think this question I asked recently has an answer you will find useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975516/can-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-be-used-here

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the Leibniz integral [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Note that $F(x+h) - F(x) = \int_0^{x} ( f(x+h,t) - f(x,t)) dt + \int_x^{x+h} f(x+h,t) dt$.

To get an intuition first, replace $f$ by a linear approximation:

\begin{eqnarray}
F(x+h) - F(x) &=& \int_0^{x} {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt \,h + \int_x^{x+h} ( f(x,t) + {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} \,h )dt \\
&=& (\int_0^{x} {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt  + f(x,t^*))h +\int_x^{x+h} {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt \, h
\end{eqnarray}
Where $t^* \in [x,x+h]$.

This suggests that $F'(x) = \int_0^{x} {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt  + f(x,x)$.

If we assume that $f$ and ${\partial f \over \partial x}$ are continuous then
using uniform continuity we establish that this is indeed true.